# android.volley does not exist

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-volley

My first time here, and I'm very new at coding so please be gentle. I'm ready to compile a signed version of the application that has been developed and I've run into a very odd set of errors that differ depending on what exactly I do.

When I clean the project, it generates a "Signed APK". When I look into the folder, there is nothing there. If I debug, build a signed apk, or run the application, I get a variety of errors stemming from the fact that volley cannot be found.

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:assembleDebug]
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:volley:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:volley:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:volley:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:volley:compileLint
:volley:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:volley:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:volley:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:volley:checkReleaseManifest
:volley:prepareReleaseDependencies
:volley:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:volley:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:volley:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:volley:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:volley:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:volley:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:volley:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:volley:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:volley:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:volley:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:volley:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:volley:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:volley:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:volley:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:volley:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:volley:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:volley:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:volley:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:volley:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2321Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72321Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2321Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72321Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42321Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2321Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidVolleyVolleyUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices840Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds840Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics840Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing840Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite840Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate840Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth840Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase840Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement840Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast840Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive840Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness840Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames840Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm840Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity840Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation840Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps840Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement840Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby840Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama840Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus840Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet840Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision840Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet840Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable840Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
C:\Users\ZZZ\src\com\appname\util\StringRequestActivity.java
Error:(14, 32) error: package com.android.volley.error does not exist
Error:(15, 34) error: package com.android.volley.request does not exist
Error:(64, 3) error: cannot find symbol class StringRequest
Error:(64, 30) error: cannot find symbol class StringRequest
Error:(77, 32) error: cannot find symbol class VolleyError
Error:(96, 3) error: cannot find symbol class StringRequest
Error:(96, 30) error: cannot find symbol class StringRequest
Error:(111, 32) error: cannot find symbol class VolleyError
Error:(137, 3) error: cannot find symbol class StringRequest
Error:(137, 30) error: cannot find symbol class StringRequest
Error:(173, 32) error: cannot find symbol class VolleyError
Error:(192, 3) error: cannot find symbol class StringRequest
Error:(192, 30) error: cannot find symbol class StringRequest
Error:(209, 34) error: cannot find symbol class VolleyError
Error:(234, 3) error: cannot find symbol class StringRequest
Error:(234, 30) error: cannot find symbol class StringRequest
Error:(260, 32) error: cannot find symbol class VolleyError
C:\Users\ZZZ\src\com\appname\FirstIntent.java
Error:(11, 32) error: package com.android.volley.error does not exist
Error:(12, 34) error: package com.android.volley.request does not exist
Error:(177, 6) error: cannot find symbol class StringRequest
Error:(177, 33) error: cannot find symbol class StringRequest
Error:(205, 35) error: cannot find symbol class VolleyError
C:\Users\appname\ForgetPassword.java
Error:(8, 32) error: package com.android.volley.error does not exist
Error:(9, 34) error: package com.android.volley.request does not exist
Error:(94, 6) error: cannot find symbol class StringRequest
Error:(94, 33) error: cannot find symbol class StringRequest
Error:(117, 35) error: cannot find symbol class VolleyError
C:\Users\appname\FragmentB.java
Error:(13, 32) error: package com.android.volley.error does not exist
Error:(14, 34) error: package com.android.volley.request does not exist
Error:(62, 3) error: cannot find symbol class StringRequest
Error:(62, 30) error: cannot find symbol class StringRequest
Error:(126, 34) error: cannot find symbol class VolleyError
Error:(166, 6) error: cannot find symbol class StringRequest
Error:(166, 33) error: cannot find symbol class StringRequest
Error:(192, 35) error: cannot find symbol class VolleyError
Error:(225, 7) error: cannot find symbol class StringRequest
Error:(225, 34) error: cannot find symbol class StringRequest
Error:(252, 36) error: cannot find symbol class VolleyError
C:\Users\appname\FragmentB_Other.java
Error:(13, 32) error: package com.android.volley.error does not exist
Error:(14, 34) error: package com.android.volley.request does not exist
Error:(78, 3) error: cannot find symbol class StringRequest
Error:(78, 30) error: cannot find symbol class StringRequest
Error:(154, 34) error: cannot find symbol class VolleyError
C:\Users\appname\FragmentDiscoverMore.java
Error:(12, 32) error: package com.android.volley.error does not exist
Error:(13, 34) error: package com.android.volley.request does not exist
Error:(129, 6) error: cannot find symbol class StringRequest
Error:(129, 33) error: cannot find symbol class StringRequest
Error:(157, 35) error: cannot find symbol class VolleyError
C:\Users\appname\OtherUserProfile.java
Error:(13, 32) error: package com.android.volley.error does not exist
Error:(14, 34) error: package com.android.volley.request does not exist
Error:(174, 3) error: cannot find symbol class StringRequest
Error:(174, 30) error: cannot find symbol class StringRequest
Error:(250, 34) error: cannot find symbol class VolleyError
C:\Users\appname\OtherUserProfileActivity.java
Error:(13, 32) error: package com.android.volley.error does not exist
Error:(14, 34) error: package com.android.volley.request does not exist
Error:(99, 3) error: cannot find symbol class StringRequest
Error:(99, 30) error: cannot find symbol class StringRequest
Error:(171, 34) error: cannot find symbol class VolleyError
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Error:Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 8.399 secs
Information:59 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer.

> **UPDATED**According to the first answer I deleted the volley file and also >deleted the dependencies as instructed. The app imported volley correctly, but >I am still getting the issue. Note, I have also updated my JAVA_HOME to the >correct location. SAME ERRORS.

[Project Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5GdP.png)
[Build gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipYYz.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead including its folder as project please include it in your app's build.gradle. It is officially available on jcenter here is the include line

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this, but I am still getting the same error message. I tried deleting the volley folder as well. Could it be that I missed something else?

Comment: as per the photos posted by you please delete volley folder from android studio and delete the line in dependencies which include volly.
Then rebuild project, after it must rebuild successfully and after that add the gradle line included by me above.
and make sure you are inserting that line in app's gradle file.
hope this helps you

Comment: Hello. I wish I could say this worked, but it did not. I also went in and updated my JAVA_HOME to make sure that wasn't the problem either. It did change a few things, so I will update my pictures. One moment please.

Comment: THIS WORKED! When I combined this with a true focus on my JAVA_HOME location I was able to get past this error. THANK YOU Chintan Desai!